# Fan runs full speed forever after waking from suspend

Tags: suspend, lenovo, thinkpad, fan, noise

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon (5th gen., type 20HR) that works wonderfully with Ubuntu 16.04 but for one thing: the fan often (but not always) comes on full after waking the laptop from suspend, and then stays in indefinitely.

Before suspending, it is quiet and does sometimes spin up for a few seconds now and then (so it seems that some sort of temperature control is working). When it stays on, it doesn't feel like it's hot at all, and the CPUs are often under 10% each.)

How can I make the fan behave itself?

Comment: It may need a UEFI update.

Comment: Maybe late, but what helps is to just close the notebook, wait for it to go back to suspend and then just reopen. Usually the fan is in normal operation then.

Comment: Thinkpad t460s: UEFI BIOS 1.44 (N1CET76W), ECP 1.14 (N1CHT32W), Ubuntu 16.04, Kernel 4.19.60 => seems fixed

Comment: I have the same on a x260. UEFI BIOS still on 1.43.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem, and after doing some research, looks like this was a kernel regression triggered by latest X1C firmware. There is a long discussion here: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=191181
And a bug report here for the X1C 5th Gen specifically: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196129

Some people are reporting those patches are working for them. But it doesn't seem a foolproof fix has made it into mainline kernel yet.

EDIT: I have been running kernel 4.12.10 for a few days now and this issue has not resurfaced. I followed these instructions to install it: https://www.tecmint.com/upgrade-kernel-in-ubuntu/. Hope this works for you as well!

Comment: triggered by this answer I updated my ubuntu to 17.10. Now, apart from a lot of my programs being broken, this problem is also not solved, although my kernel version is now 4.13.0..

Comment: I installed ubuntu 18.04 with kernal version 4.15 and have this issue