# Fan going full blast on laptop after suspend

Tags: suspend, lenovo, 17.04, fan, fancontrol

I recently got a Lenovo X1 Yoga and slapped a copy of Xubuntu 17.04 on it.  I'm having this issue where the laptop fan will go from 0 to MAX after coming back from a suspended state.  This happens after I close the lid or when pressing the `Suspend` button in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

I found a viable solution in this question: [Fan runs full speed forever after waking from suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/942473/fan-runs-full-speed-forever-after-waking-from-suspend)

The `tl;dr` is that there was a bit of a bug in v4.10 of the kernel.  The solution is to manually update to the latest version of the Kernel (v4.13 at the time of writing this).  Following the guide from here: https://www.tecmint.com/upgrade-kernel-in-ubuntu/

You'll need to:

1. Go here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/, Scroll to the bottom to find the latest release (I **don't** recommend getting one marked with `RC`)
2. Grab the headers and image for your architecture (You'll probably want the ones marked `generic`.  I my case I used:

   - linux-headers-4.13.0-041300_4.13.0-041300.201709031731_all.deb
   - linux-headers-4.13.0-041300-generic_4.13.0-041300.201709031731_amd64.deb
   - linux-image-4.13.0-041300-generic_4.13.0-041300.201709031731_amd64.deb
3. Where you save them to, run `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`
4. Reboot your system.

You should be good to go after that.  This issue will probably go away when more up to date versions of the kernel make their way into the Ubuntu repos, but this is what you'll have to do in the meantime.